# Package version creation is failing in VS code when AccountContactRelation object is referred in Apex class

Tags: package

We have enabled 'Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts' setting both is our scratch org and VS code, AccountContactRelation object is referred in our apex classes and the functionality works fine in SF but when we try creating the package version with this change in VS code we are getting error message saying Invalid type: Schema.AccountContactRelation.

We tried by enabling the 'Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts' setting in Dev hub org also.
Issue is happening in new scratch org created and after compiling all the apex classes as well.

Please find below screenshot for more details on the issue and help us resolve the same
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify this feature in your [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm), and then add that file to your package configuration in [sfdx-project.json](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm). You'll use this file both to create new Scratch Orgs with this setting automatically enabled, as well as creating package versions that have this dependency turned on.

## config/project-scratch-def.json

```
{
  ... other settings here ...
  "features": [ "ContactsToMultipleAccounts" ]
}
```

## sfdx-project.json

```
{
  ... other stuff here ...
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      ... other package stuff here ...
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json"
    }
  ]
}
```